# Can't insert more than 1 entity (batch insert) with Azure - JAVA

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to insert a batch of Entities with Azure.
For my "CustomerEntity", all works as expected, but for my "OrderEntity", I can only have a single entity in my batch operation...

Here is my code:

```
public void batchInsertTransaction(ArrayList<Transaction> transactions){

    try
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
           CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

        // Define a batch operation.
        TableBatchOperation batchCustomerOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
        TableBatchOperation batchOrderOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

        // Create a cloud table object for the table.
        CloudTable cloudCustomerTable = tableClient.getTableReference("Customer");
        CloudTable cloudOrderTable = tableClient.getTableReference("Order");

        String partitionKey = "transaction-" + PropertiesManager.country + "-" + PropertiesManager.city;

        for(int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); i++){

            Transaction transaction = transactions.get(i);
            Order order = transaction.getOrder();
            Customer customer = transaction.getCustomer();              

             // Create a customer entity to add to the table.
            CustomerEntity customerEntity = new CustomerEntity(partitionKey, customer.getGlobalId());
            customerEntity.setCountry(customer.getCountry());
            customerEntity.setName(customer.getName());
            customerEntity.setGlobalId(customer.getGlobalId());
            batchCustomerOperation.insertOrReplace(customerEntity);

            OrderEntity orderEntity = new OrderEntity(partitionKey, order.getGlobalId());
            orderEntity.setComplete(order.getComplete());
            orderEntity.setCustomerId(order.getCustomerId());
            orderEntity.setGlobalId(order.getGlobalId());
            orderEntity.setOrderDate(order.getOrderDate());
            orderEntity.setPrice(order.getPrice());
            orderEntity.setSku(order.getSku());
            orderEntity.setId(order.getId());               
            batchOrderOperation.insertOrReplace(orderEntity);

        }

       // Execute the batch of operations on the "people" table.
        cloudCustomerTable.execute(batchCustomerOperation);
        cloudOrderTable.execute(batchOrderOperation);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here is my "OrderEntity"

```
package entities;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity;

public class OrderEntity extends TableServiceEntity  {

int orderId;
int customerId;
String globaOrderlId;
String sku;
String orderDate;
double price;
int complete;

public OrderEntity(){ }

public OrderEntity(String partitionKey, String globalId){
    this.partitionKey = partitionKey;
    this.rowKey = globalId;
}

public void setComplete(int complete){
    this.complete = complete;
}

public void setCustomerId(int id){
    this.customerId = id;
}

 public void setGlobalId(String id){
        this.globaOrderlId = id;
 }

 public void setPrice(double price){
     this.price = price;
 }

 public void setOrderDate(String date){
     this.orderDate = date;
 }

 public void setSku(String sku){
     this.sku = sku;
 }    

public void setId(int id){
    this.orderId = id;
}

public String getGlobalId(){
    return this.globaOrderlId;
}

public int getId(){
    return this.orderId;
}

public int getCustomerId(){
    return this.customerId;
}

public String getSku(){
    return this.sku;
}

public String getOrderDate(){
    return this.orderDate;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return this.price;
}

public int getComplete(){
    return this.complete;
}
}
```

I have tried commenting out the customer code, as well as all of the order entity set properties, but still... I can only have a single entity in my "batchOrderOperation".

If I have any more, I get an error:

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceException: Bad Request at
com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableBatchOperation$1.postProcessResponse(TableBatchOperation.java:548)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableBatchOperation$1.postProcessResponse(TableBatchOperation.java:434)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:148)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableBatchOperation.execute(TableBatchOperation.java:419)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:495)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:452)
at managers.TableManager.batchInsertTransaction(TableManager.java:120)
at managers.QueueManager.process(QueueManager.java:40)
at App.main(App.java:32)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You should use Fiddler to intercept the operation and verify the actual request and response. This is nearly always the fastest way to identify problems while using Azure Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny how I spend hours looking for the solution and as soon as I resort to asking for help, I find the answer...

It turns out that my rowKeys were identical, and rowKeys must be unique for any given partition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338.aspx

> The row key is a unique identifier for an entity within a given
>   partition

Hope this helps someone else one day.